# Linux PAM rule "pam_unix.so" module above "pam_faillock"

Tags: linux, pam

I would like to know what this below PAM rule

```
auth [success=1 default=bad] pam_unix.so
```

above the **pam_faillock.so** rule is doing

```
auth required pam_faillock.so preauth audit silent deny=5 unlock_time=0
```

The complete set of **pam_faillock.so** rules in **/etc/pam.d/system-auth-ac** are like this:

```
auth required pam_faillock.so preauth audit silent deny=5 unlock_time=0 
auth [success=1 default=bad] pam_unix.so 
auth [default=die] pam_faillock.so authfail audit deny=5 unlock_time=0 
auth sufficient pam_faillock.so authsucc audit deny=5 unlock_time=0
```

Answer (score 1):

`pam_unix.so` is the PAM module that handles authentication based on the traditional Unix files (`/etc/passwd`, `/etc/shadow`, etc.). `success=1` tells PAM to skip the next module when authentication was successful (so it skips the `authfail` case of `pam_faillock.so` and goes directly to the `authsucc` case).

Essentially this module is what allows you to login in the first place.